# Open neighborhoods on the blow-up of projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

Does every point of blow-up of the projective space along some smooth subvariety, have a neighborhood that is an open subset of affine space (i.e. $\mathbb{A}^n$)? I'm interested in char $p$ case.

Comment: You can get non-smooth total spaces by blowing up singular subvarieties, so you had better add some conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I added the smoothness condition.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99144/local-structure-of-rational-varieties